# Flutter: Build resource-intensive widgets consecutively

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `Stack` with multiple keyed `AnimatedPositioned`.
The `AnimatedPositioned` each have a `child` with some resource-intensive Widget `HeavyToBuildWidget`.

I don't want to go into detail how `HeavyToBuildWidget` can be optimized, we assume that it needs ~2ms to be built.
Now i want to create 1000 of `HeavyToBuildWidget` - and, as expected, it takes 2000ms to build the view.

Is it possible to "schedule" the widget building, so that only 5 of `HeavyToBuildWidget` get rendered every second? It does >>not<< matter, if it takes ~200 seconds to build, but the 2000ms jank is not acceptable and i'd rather like to spread the heavy workload. I'm very careful with `setState`, and i will not rebuild them.

Please do not go into details how to improve building-time for `HeavyToBuildWidget`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a `statefullWidget` you put a property containing the list of `AnimatedPositioned` widgets:

```
List<AnimatedPositioned> stackWidgets = [];
```

Then, inside the initState callback, you run a periodic `Stream`:

```
initState(){
  super.initState();
  Stream.periodic(duration: Duration(seconds: 5),).listen((){
    setState(() {
      stackWidgets.add(/*value*/); // add one of the 1000 widgets.
      stackWidgets.add(/*value*/); // add another.
      stackWidgets.add(/*value*/); // add another.
      stackWidgets.add(/*value*/); // add another.
      stackWidgets.add(/*value*/); // add another.
    });
  });
}
```

Every 5 seconds, the screen will get updated: Another item will get added to the stack.